# Enviar correo a multiples contactos Ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Tengo un ejemplo de envío de correos utilizando email composer.
Al momento envío correos a un usuario, pero quisiera saber cómo envío un mismo email a un array de contactos.

a continuación comparto mi código:

app.js

```
.controller('General', function($scope){
  $scope.EnvioMail= function() {
    $scope.contactos=[{correo:"Mail1@gmail.com"},{correo:"mail2@gmail.com"},{correo:"mail3@gmail.com"},{correo:"mail4@gmail.com"}];
    for(var i=0; i<$scope.contactos.length;i++){
      alert($scope.contactos[i].correo);
    }
    $scope.nombre="ejemplo@gmail.com";
    if(window.plugins && window.plugins.emailComposer) {
      window.plugins.emailComposer.showEmailComposerWithCallback(function(result) {
       alert("Response ->");
      }, 
      "Esta es una prueba para enviar mails desde tu aplicacion ionic", // Subject
      "",                      // Body
      [$scope.nombre],    // To EN ESTA PARTE QUIERO ENVIARLE A $scope.contactos[i].correo
      null,                    // CC
      null,                    // BCC
      false,                   // isHTML
      null,                    // Attachments
      null);                   // Attachment Data
    }
  }
})
```

index.html

```
<ion-content ng-controller='General'>
  <br><br>
  <button class="button button-assertive" ng-click="EnvioMail()">enviar mail</button>
</ion-content>
```

En sí lo que deseo es enviar dicho correo a `$scope.contactos[i].correo`

Comment: Prueba de hacer primero una prueba manual, pon varios correo separados por `;` a ver si te funciona. Si es así luego te ayudo a programar la creación del string separado por `;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crea un array con solo los correos. Puedes utilizar la función map() para ello:

```
$scope.listaCorreos = $scope.contactos.map(
  function(contacto){ 
    return contacto.correo;
  });
```

Así, listaCorreos será:

```
 ["Mail1@gmail.com","mail2@gmail.com","mail3@gmail.com","mail4@gmail.com"]
```

Por norma general, lo ideal sería que por protección de datos y privacidad un receptor del correo electrónico no viese a quién más se ha enviado el correo (a menos que sea entre compañeros de trabajo, amigos, etc.).

Por lo tanto, lo que yo suelo hacer es enviar el correo a la misma cuenta que lo envía, y añadir en BCC (el resto de remitentes oculto) las direcciones destinatarias:

```
window.plugins.emailComposer.showEmailComposerWithCallback(function(result) {
           alert("Response ->");
          }, 
          "Esta es una prueba para enviar mails desde tu aplicacion ionic", // Subject
          "",                      // Body
          "email@empresa.com",     // O directamente $scope.listaCorreos
          null,                    // CC
          $scope.listaCorreos,     // BCC
          false,                   // isHTML
          null,                    // Attachments
          null);                   // Attachment Data
```

Comment: Es una excelente respuesta. Muchas gracias